# FB.login works but pop up doesn't close

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, popup, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am calling FB.login from a javascript function :

```
<a onclick="loggin()">login facebook</a>

function loggin (){ 
FB.login(function(response) {           
   if (response.authResponse) {
     window.location.reload();
   }
 });
}
```

The popup opens, I can login but after the popup login doesn't close.The page remains empty at this url :

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=...

I have the same behaviour in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I am running my application on the port 80 and my facebook application is correctly configured with the right URL.

Could anyone help me ?

Regards

Comment: I am running the app in localhost

Comment: I have no response after :

FB.login(function(response) {

Comment: Any luck @HappyLearner ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this is too old but you may try this:

```
function loggin (){ 
FB.login(function(response) {           
   if (response.authResponse) {
     window.location.reload();
     return false;
   }
 });
}
```